# Web ui (ASP.NET based) to run integration tests written for NUnit

Tags: asp.net, nunit, integration-testing

I want to be able to run and see the results of NUnit-based integration tests using some ASP.NET based UI (as opposed to regular windows based NUnit GUI). Is there an open source or commerical package already available? Note I'm not talking about testing ASP.NET or web apps.I want to run tests in code behind but see the results in Web browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a ALM tool like TeamCity?

If you setup a build to run your unit tests you would be able to view the results after they run..

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

Answer (score 0):

Check out CruiseControl.NET which will allow you to display the output of NUnit tests after execution.